# MySQL Select * On Every Table During Insert

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a MySQL database with a single Replica. Statement-Based-Replication is being used.

Every time there is an insert into the Master database, the root user executes a SELECT /*40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */* FROM on all the tables. The web application that is using this database, which is set up to read from the Replica, hangs until this query is finished. Several of the tables are large and the query can take ~ 30 seconds where it gets stuck in a "Writing to net" state.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any triggers?

Comment: No triggers are set up.

Comment: So the query kicks off on the master? Also what [replication format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-formats.html) are you using?

Comment: Yes, the query kicks off on master. It is set up using Statement-Based-Replication.